# Git hooks environment variables missing

Tags: git, bash, digital-ocean, githooks, pm2

I am creating a custom build system for my node app on Digital Ocean which involves git hooks to install dependencies and start the app. Part of the app config reads sensitive data (which cannot be checked into the repo) from environment variables. In my git hook I stop the app using an external script, copy the repo files (from `SOURCE_REPO` to `SOURCE_DIR` (should have named the variables better, really) and restart the app:

```
# hooks/post-receive
# go to the www repo and stop the app
cd $SOURCE_DIR
if [ -f tools/staging-stop.sh ]; then
    echo "Stopping the staging app..."
    tools/staging-stop.sh
fi

cd $SOURCE_REPO
git --work-tree=${SOURCE_DIR} checkout --force
cd $SOURCE_DIR

if [ -f tools/staging-start.sh ]; then
    echo "Starting the staging app..."
    tools/staging-start.sh
fi


# tools/staging-stop.sh
node_modules/.bin/pm2 stop staging
# updates env vars
node_modules/.bin/pm2 delete staging

# tools/stating-start.sh
source /etc/profile.d/my_env_vars.sh
yarn install --production=true
NODE_ENV=staging node_modules/.bin/pm2 start build/index.js --name staging
```

However, for a reason I cannot pinpoint, the environment variables in `/etc/profile.d/my_env_vars.sh` (which I assume should be available without sourcing them) are not present when the git hook launches the app. However, if I `ssh` into the server and manually start the app with pm2, the environment vars are available, so I am guessing this has to do with the git hook itself and the kind of shell it launches.

I'd really appreciate help on this one.